# enum errors expected an identifier and other 2

Tags: c++, enums

I'm getting: **expected an identifier** and **a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "trivia"** x2

This is my code, sorry, I'm new in programming so I'm testing stuff :)

```
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum trivia[1][2]
{
    {"Hello there", "Hi"}
};
```

Comment: This seems very odd for an enum. What are you actually trying to do? I am not sure you want an enum at all.

Comment: C++ is a very unforgiving language when it comes to "Just trying stuff out." You'll find that sometimes that stuff you tried out only looked like it worked. Definitely try stuff out, but you have to be able to confirm that what you're trying is in fact legal code and not exploiting what's known as [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are using the enumeration is not correct. The enums are used to hold constants with meaningful names that are to be used during coding. This is done to increase the readability of the code.

A sample enum example is as follows:

```cpp
enum Color { red, green, blue };
//            0     1     2
Color r = red;

switch(r) {
    case red  : std::cout << "red\n";   break; // case 0
    case green: std::cout << "green\n"; break; // case 1
    case blue : std::cout << "blue\n";  break; // case 2
}
```

---

If you want to store an array of strings, then why not do it like this:

```
std::string trivia[] = {"String 1", "String 2"};
```

or, C-like arrays:

```
const char *trivia[][128] = {"String 1", "String 2"};
```

Comment: thx, i was used with pawn enums :) an old programming language :D